# Estouro de memória com mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli, windows, xampp, memory-leaks

A seguinte instrução travou o programa: 
`$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base');`

E retornou o seguinte erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 4194312 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\combina.php on
>   line 57

A tabela `base` estava com pouco menos de **3 milhões de registros**, sendo que esta tabela tem apenas **3 campos** `int(10)`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu penso que `mysqli_query` não deveria carregar todo o conteúdo da tabela na memória, certo?

Então, por qual razão o estouro da memória?

Abaixo o código:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "comb";

$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$db) {
    die("Falha na conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base');
```

Comment: Query dentro de loop raramente é boa solução. Precisa por todo o trecho relevante de código (de preferência com o loop mencionado), senão não dá pra analisar. E se precisa de dados parcialmente, usualmente cabe um LIMIT para dividir em lotes. Fora isso, tem o "use result" e "save result", cada um com um comportamento. Da forma como está, a pergunta não é clara o suficiente para uma conclusão que não dependa de "chute". Seria o caso de [edit] e por o código relevante na postagem (com o devido cuidado de ocultar senhas e servidor, claro).

Comment: É independente de estar em um loop. Colocando a instrução logo no começo também dá o mesmo problema. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Ainda valem as considerações acima sobre o USE vs SAVE e a aplicação de LIMIT. Tem também alguns fatores que são afetados pelo php.ini (ou equivalente) na configuração das libs.

Comment: Poderia demonstrar como fazer isso no código?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM base LIMIT 1,10000` por exemplo. Lembrando que de qualquer forma, você vai acabar precisando executar o PHP em linha de comando provavelmente se for alguma tarefa demorada, pra não travar o servidor de páginas e nem ter problemas de timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado no comentário de @Bacco, pesquisei e percebi que realmente o comando `mysqli_query` carrega TODOS os registros na RAM. Ou seja, para tabelas grandes, vai realmente gerar uma limitação de memória.

A solução que encontrei foi usar a combinação de [mysqli_real_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-query.php) (que ativará a query **sem carregar todos os registros na RAM**, [mysqli_use_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.use-result.php) (que retornará o objeto resultante **não bufferizado**) e finalmente [mysqli_fetch_row](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) que lerá o resultado linha a linha.

Desta forma a solução para o problema apresentado seria mais ou menos:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_real_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base');
$result = mysqli_use_result($db);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) ...
```